# Dimension does not match when using `keras.Model.fit` in `BERT` of tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, nlp, tensorflow-datasets, bert-language-model, tensorflow-data-validation

I follow the instruction of [Fine-tuning BERT](https://www.tensorflow.org/official_models/fine_tuning_bert?hl=en) to build a model with my own dataset(It is kind of large, and greater than 20G),  then take steps to re-cdoe my data and load them from `tf_record` files.
The `training_dataset` I create has the same signature as that in the instruction

```
training_dataset.element_spec

({'input_word_ids': TensorSpec(shape=(32, 1024), dtype=tf.int32, name=None), 
'input_mask': TensorSpec(shape=(32, 1024), dtype=tf.int32, name=None), 
'input_type_ids': TensorSpec(shape=(32, 1024), dtype=tf.int32, name=None)}, 
TensorSpec(shape=(32,), dtype=tf.int32, name=None))
```

where `batch_size` is 32, `max_seq_length` is 1024.
As the instruction suggestes,

```
The resulting tf.data.Datasets return (features, labels) pairs, as expected by keras.Model.fit
```

It semms that everything works as expected,(the instruction does not show how to use `training_dataset` though ) However, the following code

```
bert_classifier.fit(
    x = training_dataset, 
    validation_data=test_dataset, # has the same signature just as training_dataset
    batch_size=32,
    epochs=epochs,
    verbose=1,
)
```

encouters an error that seems weird to me,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/captain/project/dataload/train.py", line 81, in <module>
    verbose=1,
  File "/home/captain/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 1100, in fit
    tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
  File "/home/captain/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 828, in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
  File "/home/captain/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 871, in _call
    self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
  File "/home/captain/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 726, in _initialize
    *args, **kwds))
  File "/home/captain/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 2969, in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected
    graph_function, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
  File "/home/captain/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 3361, in _maybe_define_function
    graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
  File "/home/captain/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 3206, in _create_graph_function
    capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),
  File "/home/captain/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py", line 990, in func_graph_from_py_func
    func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
  File "/home/captain/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 634, in wrapped_fn
    out = weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
  File "/home/captain/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py", line 977, in wrapper
    raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
ValueError: in user code:

    /home/captain/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:805 train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    /home/captain/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/official/nlp/keras_nlp/layers/position_embedding.py:88 call  *
        return tf.broadcast_to(position_embeddings, input_shape)
    /home/captain/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py:845 broadcast_to  **
        "BroadcastTo", input=input, shape=shape, name=name)
    /home/captain/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py:750 _apply_op_helper
        attrs=attr_protos, op_def=op_def)
    /home/captain/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py:592 _create_op_internal
        compute_device)
    /home/captain/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:3536 _create_op_internal
        op_def=op_def)
    /home/captain/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:2016 __init__
        control_input_ops, op_def)
    /home/captain/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:1856 _create_c_op
        raise ValueError(str(e))

    ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 512 and 1024 for '{{node bert_classifier/bert_encoder_1/position_embedding/BroadcastTo}} = 
BroadcastTo[T=DT_FLOAT, Tidx=DT_INT32](bert_classifier/bert_encoder_1/position_embedding/strided_slice_1, bert_classifier/bert_encoder_1/position_embedding/Shape)' 
with input shapes: [512,768], [3] and with input tensors computed as partial shapes: input[1] = [32,1024,768].
```

There is nothing to do with 512, and I didn't use 512 thorough my code. So where is wrong with my code and how to fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They created the `bert_classifier` based on `bert_config_file` loaded from `bert_config.json`

```
bert_classifier, bert_encoder = bert.bert_models.classifier_model(bert_config, num_labels=2)
```

bert_config.json

```
{
'attention_probs_dropout_prob': 0.1,
 'hidden_act': 'gelu',
 'hidden_dropout_prob': 0.1,
 'hidden_size': 768,
 'initializer_range': 0.02,
 'intermediate_size': 3072,
 'max_position_embeddings': 512,
 'num_attention_heads': 12,
 'num_hidden_layers': 12,
 'type_vocab_size': 2,
 'vocab_size': 30522
}
```

According to this config, `hidden_size` is 768 and `max_position_embeddings` is 512 so your input data used to feed to BERT model must be the same shape as described. It explains the reason why you are getting the shape-mismatched issue.

Therefore, to make it work, you have to change all lines for creating tensor inputs from `1024` to `512`.

Comment: I see, Thanks a lot. Maybe I can change the 'max_sequence_length' instead.

Comment: If you want to truncate the inputs to make them shorter, you can adjust `max_sequence_length` to be 128, 256 or 384 and the remaining elements will be filled with a special padding token `[PAD]` when we encode the inputs.